# Embeddings of Boolean algebras in $\wp(\omega)/Fin$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, boolean-algebras

If we assume MA+¬CH, then every boolean algebra with cardinality smaller than the continuum embeds in ℘(ω)/Fin. A proof of this result can be found in Theorem 1.1, Chapter 8 of the book "Hausdorff gaps and limits". In the paper "R. Frankiewicz, Some remarks on embeddings of boolean algebras and topological spaces II, Fund. Math, 126 (1), 1985, 63-68.", the author showed that it is consistent with MA+¬CH the existence of a boolean algebra with cardinality equal to the continuum which does not embed in ℘(ω)/Fin.

Is it consistent with $MA+\neg CH$ that every boolean algebra with cardinaly equal to the continuum embeds in ℘(ω)/Fin?

Comment: Apparently there are some errors in Frankiewicz's paper: see section 5.2 of ["The measure algebra does not always embed", by Dow and Hart](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9905016.pdf).  On the other hand the result as stated is still true; Dow and Hart show that under OCA, the measure algebra doesn't embed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the paper [Embedding of Boolean algebras in $Ρ(ω)/$fin](https://eudml.org/doc/211828) the following partial result  is proved:

**Theorem** There is a model of $ZFC$ with arbitrarily large continuum in which each Boolean algebra $B$ of cardinality  $\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ can be embedded into $P(ω)/$fin. In addition, Martin's axiom for $σ$-linked orderings holds in the model.

You may also look at [On automorphisms of Boolean algebras embedded in P (ω)/fin](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm150/fm15023.pdf), where a model as above is constructed in which the following additional property holds:  every automorphism of $B$ extends to an automorphism of $P(ω)/$fin.

Comment: @ClaudiaCorrea Adding to the last paragraph in Mohammad's answer, it is worth mentioning that based on a result of Shelah and Steprāns, Proper Forcing Axiom implies that $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$/Fin has no non-trivial automorphism. See: "*[PFA implies all automorphisms are trivial.](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=935111)*"

Comment: @MortezaAzad A result of Velickovic says that $OCA+MA_{\aleph_1}$ is enough. This is even enough for $P(\omega_1}/fin$.

Comment: @Rahman.M (+1) Mamnun Rahman jaan! :-) Could you please add a link to that particular work of Velicovic that you cited in your comment? Or maybe it is an unpublished result?

Comment: @MortezaAzad, You are welcome. Here is the link. http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~boban/pdf/OCA-automorphisms.pdf